# Cross controller variables

Tags: playframework

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520776/1193291) I was wondering what would be the best way to "superclass the controller" in my app.

I have several controllers that require different security, but, they use the same set of persisted variables in templates. Does this look like the right approach?

```
public class Globals extends Controller {
  @Before
  static void setGlobals() {
    renderArgs.set("foo","bar");
  }
}
```

Then annotate controllers @With interceptor

```
@With([Globals.class, mySecurity.class])
public class Application extends Controller {
  // my methods
}
```

Cool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using @With annotation is the way that play recommended. But you are free to use inheritance if no other side effect

Comment: So you we could just as easily done: Application extends Global. That would be more DRY. Thanks for the feedback.