# How to manage per application defined properties (based on an XML)

Tags: playframework

I have a general XML file containing different properties for my Play! application like:

- customer location of CSS file
- preffered dateTime format for user
- other specific resources that I need for my application

So when starting Play! I want to load these resource once in Play!. Once loaded they will not change. I want to avoid to load the external XML file on each request. So what I have done is the following:

Created a class that follows the singleton pattern to load the XML file.
Then created a `Model` that contains all my application properties that I need. This class has `private properties` so I instantiate this `Model` everywhere where I need it like:

```
myAppProperties = new AppProperties();
```

This question might be similar like questions about `Globals` : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/play-framework/global$20variables/play-framework/Q9DBAQtQWYc/OnS0e4dXAhAJ and [Cross controller variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334431/cross-controller-variables)

Would love to hear some feedback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to load properties is usually via the application.conf. You can also define them in other conf file and use include. If you need to centralise all your properties define your AppProperties as:

```
public class AppProperties {
   public static final String DATE_FORMAT = Play.configuration.getProperty("myapp.dateformat");
}
```

and in your application.conf:

```
myapp.dateformat = yyMMdd
```

Comment: I want to deliver my app as a WAR file to deploy on the TomCat. Can I somehow define an external conf file that should be included when starting play? Because I want to avoid that customers needs to open the war file and make changes, since my upgrade steps is to overwrite the current war file?

Comment: You can define an additional configuration file outside your war directory and include it from your application.conf. Something like: @include.app=c:\\conf\\app.conf